# 74HC161 synchronous counter

Tags: digital-logic

I have one question on the 74HC161 synchronous counter, you can find the datasheet here:

[DATASHEET](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/15545/PHILIPS/74HC161.html)

How can it be used as a downwards counter?
Actually, is it reversible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HC161 is an up counter. You need an HC191 for an up/down counter.

You could re-interpret the outputs as negative (active low) logic. Depending on what you are doing, this mind flip will often work.

Answer (score 0):

This device only counts up.  You either have to invert the outputs (using an additional device) or use a different counter.